# Web Audio API: Start Multiple MediaElementAudioSourceNode's simultaneously

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am attempting to create a multi-track audio player using the Web Audio API. Currently my play-button click is handled like this...

```
function playProject(){
    var p = $(".play-button");
    p.hide();
    p.siblings('.pause-button').show();
    for( var i=0 ; i<audio.length ; i++ ){
        audio[i].play();
    }
}
```

And my Web Audio setup looks like this...

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

var audio = [];
var channelVolume = [];
var vol = audioCtx.createGain();

$(document).ready(function(){
var obj = JSON.parse('<?php echo $json ?>');

var audioPath = "../wp-content/themes/blankslate-child/projects/"+"<?php echo     $data->name ?>"+"/";

var sources = [];
var merger = audioCtx.createChannelMerger(2);

for(var i = 0; i<obj.length;i++){
    audio.push(new Audio());
    audio[i].src = audioPath+obj[i].name;
    audio[i].loop = true;
    sources.push(audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio[i]));
    channelVolume.push(audioCtx.createGain())
    sources[i].connect(channelVolume[i]);
    channelVolume[i].connect(merger,0,0);
}

merger.connect(vol);
vol.connect(audioCtx.destination);

})
```

Essentially I loop through all of my audio elements and play them. While this works, I feel that it might not be the cleanest way to do it. Is there any way to play all of the audio sources at the same time with a single function call?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should be careful about echoing data in to JavaScript.  What you should be doing is using `json_encode()` to make your data safe for use in a script.  Also, you don't need `JSON.parse()` in JS if you echo the JSON correctly directly into the JS.

Comment: I did used json encode to create the $json variable @Brad

Comment: Right, but your missing it in your `audioPath`.  Also, you don't need `JSON.parse()`... you can echo the JSON-encoded object directly into the script.

Comment: I've decided to switch to audiobuffers instead of the html source nodes, in spite of the warnings that they are only for short sounds. They have alot more features, and timing-wise they are much more exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, the `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` has no timing guarantees.

It might work on some browser for example Firefox, in certain cases, and for now, because the way we designed things internally brings you this synchronization, but it might change from a release to the next so I wouldn't depend on it.